# How to crop a video (such as a zoom call) into multiple files?

Tags: python, node.js, opencv, video, video-streaming

I have conferance call video with different people's tiles arranged on a grid.

Example:
[gallery view zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHH3Z.png)

Can I crop every video tile to a separate file using python or nodejs?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that using OpenCV library

1. Read the video in OpenCV using VideoCapture API. Note down framerate while reading.
2. Parse through each frame and crop the frame:
3. Write the frame in a video using OpenCV VideoWriter

Here is the example code using (640,480) to be the new dimensions:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(<video_file_name>)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('<output video file name>, -1, fps, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    crop_frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # write the crooped frame
    out.write(crop_frame)

# Release reader wand writer after parsing all frames
cap.release()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code (tested). It works by initialising a number of video outputs, then for each frame of the input video: cropping the region of interest (roi) and assigning each to the relevent output video. You might need to make tweaks depending on input video dimensions, number of times, offsets etc.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('in.mp4')
ret, frame = cap.read()
(h, w, d) = np.shape(frame)

horiz_divisions = 5 # Number of tiles stacked horizontally
vert_divisions = 5 # Number of tiles stacked vertically
divisions = horiz_divisions*vert_divisions # Total number of tiles

seg_h = int(h/vert_divisions) # Tile height
seg_w = int(w/horiz_divisions) # Tile width

# Initialise the output videos
outvideos = [0] * divisions

for i in range(divisions):
    outvideos[i] = cv2.VideoWriter('out{}.avi'.format(str(i)),cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (seg_w,seg_h))

# main code
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        vid = 0 # video counter
        for i in range(vert_divisions):
            for j in range(horiz_divisions):

                # Get the coordinates (top left corner) of the current tile
                row = i * seg_h
                col = j * seg_w
                roi = frame[row:row+seg_h,col:col+seg_w,0:3] # Copy the region of interest
                outvideos[vid].write(roi)
                vid += 1
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release all the objects
cap.release()
for i in range(divisions):
    outvideos[i].release()
# Release everything if job is finished
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great! The only thing I would like to add, do we really need to loop in every tile? We can create multiple frames roi_tile and write all together in respective video objects.

Comment: @sam Yes, we could create 25 different roi variables and write the line .write() 25 times if you wanted, but it's much neater this way and also makes the code more general. This way, it will be easy to adapt the code to a different number of tiles - just change the two variables at the top.